# Concavity of $\log u(x)$

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, convex-analysis, spectral-theory

Let $u>0$ be a solution of the following equation 
$$\begin{cases}-[|u'(x)|^{p-2}u'(x)]'=\lambda_1\cdot u(x)^{p-1}&,x \in (a,b)\\u(a)=u(b)=0 \end{cases},$$
where $\lambda_1$ is the minimum of the Rayleigh quotient and $p>1.$

Prove that the function $\log u(x)$ is concave on $(a,b).$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: To make the second derivative of "log". but the question is : can I use the case when only $p=2?$

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to see that $\lambda_1>0$. From the first equation, one has
$$ -(p-2)|u'(x)|^{p-3}\frac{u'(x)}{|u'(x)|}u''(x)u'(x)-|u'(x)|^{p-2}u''(x)=\lambda_1u(x)^{p-1} $$
or
$$ -(p-1)|u'(x)|^{p-2}u''(x)=\lambda_1u(x)^{p-1}. $$
from which it is easy to see
$$ u''(x)=-\frac{\lambda_1}{p-1}\frac{u(x)^{p-1}}{|u'(x)|^{p-2}}<0. \tag{1} $$
So by (1), one has
\begin{eqnarray*} (\ln u(x))''&=&\left(\frac{1}{u(x)}u'(x)\right)'\\
&=&-\frac{1}{u(x)^2}|u'(x)|^2+\frac{1}{u(x)}u''(x)\\
&=&-\frac{1}{u(x)^2}|u'(x)|^2+\frac{1}{u(x)}u''(x)\\
&<&0.
\end{eqnarray*}
Namely $\ln u(x)$ is concave.